# Cross Apply Values (1, columnName) as (code, display) in LINQ

Tags: sql, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-core

I have an entity like:

```
public class TEvent
{
   
        public int? January { get; set; }
        public int? February { get; set; }
        public int? March { get; set; }
        public int? April { get; set; }
        public int? May { get; set; }
        public int? June { get; set; }
        public int? July { get; set; }
        public int? August { get; set; }
        public int? September { get; set; }
        public int? October { get; set; }
        public int? November { get; set; }
        public int? December { get; set; }
        //and much more
}
```

What I want my LINQ code to achieve:

```sql
SELECT MonthCode, * FROM T_Events
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1, January), (2, February), (3, March), (4, April), (5, May), (6, June), (7, July), (8, August), (9, September), (10, October), (11, November), (12, December)) AS CA(MonthCode, Display)
WHERE Display = -1
```

The problem is that I don't know how to have LINQ know it is a column name.

What I've tried

```
var dd = new List<object>()
{
    new {January = 1 },
    new {February = 2},
    new {March = 3},
    new {April = 4},
    new { May = 5},
    new {June = 6},
    new {July = 7},
    new {Augest = 8},
    new {September = 9},
    new {October = 10},
    new {November = 11},
    new {December = 12}
};

var q = 
     from events in _context.TEvents
     from mds in dd
```

Now when I write `mds.` I don't get anything because of course it is of type object, but if I don't use object how would I specify custom column names and get the value of 'Display'

Expected result:
[image: Teh result of the above query(SQL)]

The value of Months(Jan, feb etc...) can be (0 or -1). When the Columns are converted to Rows, I get 12 rows, each with it's own MonthCode and display, now let's say for a record March and April are -1, then the 3rd and 4th record will have Display = -1 and the rest will have 0, while all will retain it's month codes

Comment: Short answer: not supported by EF Core, but can be achieved by third party extensions.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the extension you're referring to @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Comment: What is result of your query? What do you expect?

Comment: I expect 12 rows for every row(because Months are in column). I've attached an image of the desired result

Comment: I see query, but which class do you expect at the end. And why TEvent has field for each month?

Comment: Just get a list of { MonthCode, Display } no need to get the whole result

Comment: Well, will propose code. But it is not clear what do you expect at the end.

Comment: I've updated the question to clear how I want the result.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore), note that I'm one of the creators.
This extension brings power of `linq2db` to EF Core projects. And library supports join to local collections.

```cs
class MonthDescription
{
    public int MonthCode { get; set; }
    public string Display { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var months = new []
{
    new MonthDescription { MonthCode = 1,  Display = "January"   },
    new MonthDescription { MonthCode = 2,  Display = "February"  },
    new MonthDescription { MonthCode = 3,  Display = "March"     },
    new MonthDescription { MonthCode = 4,  Display = "April"     },
    new MonthDescription { MonthCode = 5,  Display = "May"       },
    new MonthDescription { MonthCode = 6,  Display = "June"      },
    new MonthDescription { MonthCode = 7,  Display = "July"      },
    new MonthDescription { MonthCode = 8,  Display = "Augest"    },
    new MonthDescription { MonthCode = 9,  Display = "September" },
    new MonthDescription { MonthCode = 10, Display = "October"   },
    new MonthDescription { MonthCode = 11, Display = "November"  },
    new MonthDescription { MonthCode = 12, Display = "December"  }
};

var query = 
     from event in _context.TEvents.ToLinqToDB() // switching LINQ provider
     from md in months
     select new 
     {
         event,
         md
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Svyatoslav Danyliv For your answer. I've also found another way to achieve what I want through Union.

First Write the main query:

```
var evAll = from child in _context.TEvents
                        join parent in _context.TEventDomains
                            on child.ID equals parent.ID
                        join p in _context.TPriorities
                            on parent.IDPriority equals p.Idpriority into PJoin
                        from p in PJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new TEventExtended(child, p.PriorityCode)
```

Now I can select for each month and union the answer. like

```
from ev in evAll
select new TEventExtended(ev, 1, ev.January))
.Union(
from ev in evAll
select new TEventExtended(ev, 2, ev.February))
...etc etc
```

Here, I created a class/record which extend TEvent by 3 properties i.e. `MonthCode, Display, Priority`, and created constructors which copies data from the original TEvent/TEventExtended
**NOTE**: If you're using C# 10. You don't need to create constructors, simply use: `new TEventExtended() with { MonthCode = 12, Display = ev.December}`
Finally after adding 12 unions

```
.Union(
from ev in evAll
select new TEventExtended(ev, 12, ev.December))
.Where(x => x.Display == -1)
.OrderBy(x => x.MonthCode >= request.Month ? x.MonthCode : x.MonthCode + 12)
.ThenBy(x => x.PCode)
.Select(x =>
new MyFinalDTO
{
    //projection
}).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Use `Concat` instead of `Union`